# javascript getting junk value for string passed from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am passing vlues to javasript function from PHP in following manner:

```
<select onChange="display_databody(<?=$manufacturers_id?>,<?=$modelID?>,this.value,<?=**$month_year**?>);">
```

Here $month_year is a string obtained from MySQL.

When javascript function is getting this value it is getting something like -8 or -13.

I have tried json_encode() but it is also not working.

Comment: What does the source code look like?

Comment: How are you assigning `$month_year`? "Obtained from MySQL" doesn't have enough detail. If it's being output as `-8` or `-13` then that is the value it has. You need to get it assigned correctly in the first place. (And I assume the stars are not in the code. It's best to quote code exactly as it appears)

Comment: just a single line of code is not enough for debugging.... give us more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brainwave and guessed that `$month_year` is a string like `1-12` for January 2012. This would result in your HTML becoming *something like*

```
 <select onChange="display_databody(2,4,this.value,1-12);">
```

and Javascript will evaluate that value (as `-11` here) when it executes the function.

Wrap your string values in single quotes. You may need to do that with the first two as well if they aren't entirely numeric. Line split here for clarity: you will probably join it back together.

```
 <select 
     onChange="display_databody(<?=$manufacturers_id?>,
     <?=$modelID?>,
     this.value,
     '<?=$month_year?>');">
```

Comment: Pefect! exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `addslashes` to escape the variables:

```
<select onChange="display_databody('<?= addslashes($manufacturers_id) ?>',
    '<?= addslashes($modelID); ?>', this.value, '<?= addslashes($month_year); ?>');">
```

Or use jQuery and `htmlspecialchars`:

```
<select onChange="display_databody(this)" 
    data-manufacturer="<?= htmlspecialchars($manufacturers_id); ?>" 
    data-monthyear="<?= htmlspecialchars($month_year); ?>">
```

Then inside your function:

```
function display_databody(dropdown) {
    var $dropdown = $(dropdown),
    dropdown_value = $dropdown.val(),
    manufacturer_id = $dropdown.data('manufacturer'),
    month_year = $dropdown.data('monthyear');

    // your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use echo to write the variable

```
<select onChange="display_databody(<?php echo $manufacturers_id ?>,<?php echo $modelID ?>,this.value,<?php echo $month_year ?>);">
```

Comment: This will make no difference to the value